# How export geodatabase version differences in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, python, arcobjects, versioning

With ArcObjects I have this code in C# to export the differences to a XML file:

```
        ESRI.ArcGIS.GeoDatabaseDistributed.IVersionDataChangesInit pVDataChgs;
        var pvTemp = new ESRI.ArcGIS.GeoDatabaseDistributed.VersionDataChanges();
        pVDataChgs = pvTemp as ESRI.ArcGIS.GeoDatabaseDistributed.IVersionDataChangesInit;
        pVDataChgs.Init(pwkspname, pParWkSpname);
        var pvDataChanges = pVDataChgs as ESRI.ArcGIS.GeoDatabaseDistributed.IDataChanges;

        //Export to an XML file
        ESRI.ArcGIS.GeoDatabaseDistributed.IExportDataChanges pDCExp;
        pDCExp = new ESRI.ArcGIS.GeoDatabaseDistributed.DataChangesExporter();
        pDCExp.ExportDataChanges(sXMLExpFile, ESRI.ArcGIS.GeoDatabaseDistributed.esriExportDataChangesOption.esriExportToXML, pvDataChanges, true);
```

I need an equivalent functions to get the same result trought ArcPy. But the closest thing I've found is this function: FeatureCompare_management.

How can I compare versions, not features one by one?

Comment: There is a Version Change Tool that describes what you're looking for however I do not see any reference to it in the Arcpy library. It may not be available. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/geodatabases/the-version-changes-command.htm

Comment: I've been looking, but apparently it's impossible

Comment: @Pilgrim, it's not impossible. You could iterate over the feature classes and tables in the databases, and run tools from the [Data Comparison toolset](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/tools/data-management-toolbox/an-overview-of-the-data-comparison-toolset.htm), as needed. Then parse and transform the resulting messages as desired...this is the tricky, code-heavy part.